# How to know where ejabberd is config

Tags: ejabberd

I am working on old project where ejabberd is used. In laravel env file this information is written

```
JABBER_SERVER=localhost
JABBER_ENV=dev
RPC_SERVER= http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:4560/RPC2
JABBER_HOST=localhost
```

when i try to find the ejabberd service on my ubuntu server i couldn't.I don't have any idea how i can find ejabberd information because i am getting an error.

```
2019-12-26 07:54:27.338 [info] <0.23787.5>@ejabberd_c2s:process_terminated:264 (tcp|<0.23786.5>) Closing c2s session for prod6067@localhost/121590970668513998469410: Connection failed: connection closed

2019-12-26 07:54:30.577 [info] <0.339.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:300 (<0.23789.5>) Accepted connection 115.186.58.62:58101 -> 172.31.42.93:5222

2019-12-26 07:54:31.390 [info] <0.23790.5>@ejabberd_c2s:handle_auth_success:423 (tcp|<0.23789.5>) Accepted c2s SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication for prod6067@localhost by mnesia backend from 

2019-12-26 07:54:32.166 [info] <0.23790.5>@ejabberd_c2s:bind:394 (tcp|<0.23789.5>) Opened c2s session for prod6067@localhost/151108589900049164879426
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can run the **ejabberdctl** shell script, then it will show many information about where ejabberd is installed:

```
$ ejabberdctl
...
Optional parameters when starting an ejabberd node:
  --config-dir dir   Config ejabberd:    /etc/ejabberd
  --config file      Config ejabberd:    /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.yml
  --ctl-config file  Config ejabberdctl: /etc/ejabberd/ejabberdctl.cfg
  --logs dir         Directory for logs: /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd
  --spool dir        Database spool dir: /usr/local/var/lib/ejabberd
  --node nodename    ejabberd node name: ejabberd@localhost
```